# Error while calling webservice from android class

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-emulator

I had written a class in android which will consume a webservice to read some data from the webservice.

When am accessing that webservice through the URL call am getting that response xml properly. I had deployed the webservice in my local server and my url something like http://localhost:8083/TestWebService/services/GetDatabaseRecords?wsdl.

Following is the code portion am using to consume webservice in my app.

```
private String METHOD_NAME = "getSupplierDetails"; // our webservice method name
private String NAMESPACE = "http://test.webservice.com/"; // Here package name in webservice with reverse order.
private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME; // NAMESPACE + method name
private static final String URL = "http://my-machine-ip:8083/TestWebService/services/GetDatabaseRecords?wsdl";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
        SoapObject so = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

Following is the exception am getting when runnning the application.

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException:null
```

Is something wrong with my code? Experts please help.

Comment: You're trying to do HTTP on the UI-thread. Use an AsyncTask or some other construction and do it off the main thread and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

As the exception suggests, you're trying to use the network (i.e. a potentially slow, blocking resource) from the main (UI) thread. Android doesn't let you do that - you should perform network access on a separate thread to keep the UI responsive.

See the ["Designing for Responsiveness"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) guidance for more details.

Comment: Yes, Android does not let you perform network operations on the UI Thread but just since 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a background thread for these kind of tasks in Android. Frankly Android provides the AsyncTask type which is exactly for what you're trying to do. Something like:

```
private class WebserviceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
 protected void doInBackground(String... parameters) {
     //do web service things here
     return result; //This is the parameter of onPostExecute, change type accordingly
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
     //do something with the result
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
WebserviceTask  task = new WebserviceTask();
task.execute("http://www.example.com/api"); //You can pass the parameters like this
```

Dont forget to add the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

line to your manifest as well.

Hope this helps